# Storing elements of different type in a vector/array in C++?

Tags: c++, interpreter, dynamic-languages, dynamic-typing

I'm trying to create a simple dynamic language interpreter in C++. I'd like to be able to declare dynamically typed arrays, but I'm not sure how to store them in some object in C++.

In Ruby/Python I can store anything I want, but what's an efficient way of doing this in C++?

(Also, if someone has a link to a *simple* open source lexer/parser/interpreter for dynamic languages like Ruby, I'd appreciate a link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to roll some custom solution based on your language's semantics. For example, you can use `boost::any` to *store* any object, but you won't be able to perform, for example, name lookups. A knowledge of some assembler is useful here because you're basically emulating that. What most people do is something like

```
struct Object {
    boost::any cppobject;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void(boost::any&, std::vector<boost::any>&)> funcs;
};

std::vector<Object> stuff;
```

When, in your hypothetical language, you have something like

```
stuff[0].hi();
```

Then you can convert it into something like

```
std::vector<boost::any> args;
// fill args
stuff.at(0).funcs["hi"](stuff.at(0).cppobject, args);
// now args holds the result
```

It's quite possible to optimize this scheme further, but not to generalize it further, as it's already maximally general.

Comment: Sounds like the best idea among the 4 responses I've got. I'll give it a try. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The way dynamic languages store universal objects is via pointers, you can do the same thing in C++.   Store a pointer to a generic "object" that you define in your C++ classes, that's an efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using unions or dynamically allocating objects of a common base type (and downcasting them as appropriate via dynamic_cast or an equivalent construct) is [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/variant.html), which allows you to write code such as:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, float, char, std::string> LangType;
std::vector<LangType> langObjects;
```

If your design allows for such an implementation, this has the advantage of being compile-time safe and avoiding any penalty imposed by use of the heap, virtual functions and polymorphic downcasts.